# Is there a good way to clone a whole EC2 stack to another availability zone?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, opsworks

I've got a dozen or so EBS backed instances of various sizes in a VPC, multiple security groups, route53 for internal name service.

I'd like to clone the whole thing to another availability zone. Has anyone done such a thing? OpsWorks appears to have that feature. Has anyone used it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[CloudFormer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html) and [CloudFormation](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) would be good tools for this.

CloudFormer lets you create AWS CloudFormation templates from resources that are already existing in your account. These generated templates are basically just JSON that expresses each type of resource that CloudFormer examined. You can then take the generated template as a base, tweak the configuration of each resource as you need, and then use the template to launch those resources.

Resources:

- [AWS Documentation - Using CloudFormer to Create AWS CloudFormation Templates from Existing AWS Resources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html)
- [AWS Documentation - CloudFormation - Working With Stacks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/stacks.html)

Comment: Awesome, that looks very promising. I'll give it a whirl and report back!

Comment: I cloned a stack to another availability zone. I had to manually copy the EBS snapshots over and there was a lot of obscure template work, and abstracting the template is a challenge. Got some help from a class at the AWS loft. Some other AWS infrastructure automation tools might be easier. I hear good things about Terraform and Salt.

Comment: i am looking for is there any way to clonse ecs cluster of micro services or your solution can help mine too.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I started using [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/intro/getting-started/install.html) and the Terraform import tool called [Terraforming](https://github.com/dtan4/terraforming). I find them much more to my liking. For one thing Terraform allows iterative changes while Cloudformation seems to want to refresh the whole stack when things change. I also find the Terraform syntax and documentation quite approachable. I'm particularly fond of variable abstraction and interpolation options. I've created core stack templates which can be re-used in various environments.